# Vuex store is undefined for the state object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, store

I am using vuex in my project, and in my state object i want to reach another state object. To do that i created a getters in my store but i'm getting "store is undefined" error. Here is my store:

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-gould-bvq2b here is the sandbox.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    members: [],
    member: {},
    messages: [
      {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
        owner: store.getters.getRandomMember,
        content: "Hello this is a test message",
        date: "06.03.2020 12:20"
      },
      {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
        owner: store.getters.getRandomMember,
        content: "Hello this is the second message",
        createdDate: "06.03.2020 12:20"
      },
      {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
        owner: store.getters.getRandomMember,
        content: "Hello this is the third message",
        createdDate: "06.03.2020 12:40"
      }
    ]
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_MEMBERS(state, membersData) {
      state.members = membersData;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    getMembers() {
      axios
        .get("https://api.github.com/orgs/github/public_members")
        .then(membersResult => {
          this.commit("SET_MEMBERS", membersResult.data);
        });
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getRandomMember: state => {
      return state.members[Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)];
    }
  },
  modules: {}
});

export default store;
```

Comment: Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-gould-bvq2b i created a sandbox here, maybe it helps @lucas

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox tells you what is wrong with your code. You're using 'store' before it was defined. I'm not sure on your entity structure but I would change your code so it does something like pick a random member when you add a message. Members is also empty at the start so it would just pick null anyway.

[image: Problem description]